# Android - set activity result on Up pressed

Tags: android, android-actionbar

As it is said in Android documentaion [Back != Up](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back). After some testing, Up button doesn't send result to parent activity when pressed if activity has been started from `startActivityForResult` method.

However, in my activity I need to pass some info in when returning back from activity.

I've tried few things:

- simply add setResukt to up action:

  ```
      public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
          switch (item.getItemId()) {
          case android.R.id.home:
              setResult(something);
              NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
              return true;
          }
          return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      }
  ```
- setting result in `onStop()` and in `onPause()`

But none of this worked out.

My question is - do you know any idea how one can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

youactivity.setResult(something) is done in your activity 2 when you are done with the work in the activity 2. say suppose you make a api call and after that you just do activity.setResult(). this sends back to the activity 1 in onActivityResult(int, int, Intent) method will be called.

Comment: so according to your answer, the first option form my tries should work, isn't it?